# How to make url alias in next js and express for posts or users that you get their data by id?

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I would like to redirect a request url with the blog/:id: formatting for a more user friendly url like the blog/blogtitle and category that i get from a  a json api.
I manage to solve this partialy by res.redirect after the app.render in my server.js.
My problem is that next.js initially searches for the url alias as a page component in my pages folder and thus i get a status code of 404 before my res.redirect.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to the specific page for each request:
(see commands on server.js)

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/blog', (req, res) => {
    // @HERE: we redirect request from /blog to /blogs for general page
    // so the detail can still be redirected to /blog
    return app.render(req, res, '/blogs')
  })

  server.get('/blog/:id', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/blog', { id: req.params.id })
  })

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

**blog.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class extends Component {
  static getInitialProps ({ query: { id } }) {
    return { blogId: id }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>blog {this.props.blogId}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**blogs.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="/blog/python">
            Learn Python – Interactive <br/> Python
        </a>
        <a href="/blog/javascript">
            Learn Javascript – Interactive <br/> Javascript
        </a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```